# Localstack not accessible on localhost:4566 using Helm chart

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm, localstack

I could not access the http://localhost:4566/health on the browser even though the svc, pods are running and healthy after checking the logs. I tried to use port-forwarding with the service name and still same error

`This site can’t be reached`

`curl http://localhost:4566/health curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4566 after 5 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

The helm chart is pasted below localstack.yaml

```
`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.localstack.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: localstack
          image: "{{ .Values.localstack.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.localstack.image.tag }}"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4566
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              value: {{ .Values.localstack.aws_access_key_id }}
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              value: {{ .Values.localstack.aws_secret_access_key }}
            - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              value: {{ .Values.localstack.aws_default_region }}
            - name: AWS_ENDPOINT_URL  
              value: {{ .Values.localstack.endpoint_url }}   
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-localstack-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-localstack
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.localstack.service.port }}
      targetPort: 4566`
```

The values.yaml is
`

```
localstack:
  fullnameOverride: localstack
  chart: localstack-chart
  nameOverride: localstack
  version: 1.0.0
  image:
    repository: localstack/localstack
    tag: latest
  aws_access_key_id: test
  aws_secret_access_key: test
  aws_default_region: eu-west-2
  service:
    type: NodePort
    port: 4566
  endpoint_url: http://localstack:4566`
```

I would want to be able top locally access the endpoint of the localstack on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done port-forward to make it accessible now I was able to do kubectl port-forward  4566:4566